# Pass props from parent to children in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 components. The component A is the parent component:

```
const A = ({children}) => {

  const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(
    children,
    (child) =>
    React.cloneElement(child, {
      test: 213
    })
  );
  return <div>{childrenWithProps}</div>
}
```

Here I clone the children and send to it the `test` prop. 
The B component looks like this:

```
const B = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <A>
            <div className="test">
                <MyChildrenComponent/>
            </div>
            </A>
        </div>
    );
};

export default B;
```

How you can see, I want to send props from `A` to the `<MyChildrenComponent/>`, but, if I try to access the props in `<MyChildrenComponent/>`, I get an empty object, but if I change from:

```
 <A>
   <div className="test">
     <MyChildrenComponent/>
  </div>
 </A>
```

to

```
 <A>
     <MyChildrenComponent/>
 </A>
```

...I get the props. Why if I removed the `<div className="test">` the trick works but with the tag not? And how to solve the issue and to get props having this `<div className="test">` wrapping my `<MyChildrenComponent/>` ?

Comment: If `<div className="test">` is the child of `A` then where else would the `test` prop be passed to?

Comment: @DrewReese, ok, is there a  trick to keep the tag and to get the props inside `MyChildrenComponent`?

Comment: Not really. The `div` isn't a react component so it doesn't really handle receiving props nor can it pass any on to its children. You *can* move the `div` elsewhere though. What is the purpose of it? Could you just assign `className="test"` to the `div` wrapping `childrenWithProps` in `A`, i.e. `<div className="test">{childrenWithProps}</div>`? Or move it into `MyChildrenComponent` and wrap what *it* renders so `MyChildrenComponent` can be the child of `A` and receive the `test` prop?

Answer (score 0):

I see here collision between 2 different usages.
In React are **One-Data-Binding** - possible to  send data from parent to child in x nested levels also, context can specify ranges of component, which data can include.

1. Passing Props

You can pass props as **props** - then it have object structure:

```
props{
 prop1: x
 prop2: y
 prop3: z 
}
```

or **destructuring**:

```
B = ({prop1, prop2, prop3}) =>
```

---

```
const A = ({children}) => {
  return <B name = {children}/>
}

const B = ({titleofProps}) => {
  return <B titleofProps = {children}/>
}
```

2. Wrapping Component

   ```
   const Wrapper = ({children}) => {
      return (
        <>{children}</>
      );
    };
   ```

and:

```
<Wrapper>
  another code, components, etc
</Wrapper>
```